# Android Xml View References

Tags: android, xml, view, android-view

Is there any list on the web of all androids xml view types (TextView, ImageView, Button...) 
as well as the attributes that go with those views. I am new to android development and would like to use a list a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs have everything you need. You can [start here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) with the `Layout`s. It gives you the different `Layout`s.

Then, on the left side, you can go through the different `View` types (input controls, events, menus, etc...)

[image]

Within each one (`Button`, `TextView`, etc...) you will see the different properties and such that each has. It also gives you which API levels the properties were added in.